# Splicing together symbols with Scala macros

Tags: scala, reflection, macros, scala-2.10, scala-macros

I am trying to call a specialized collections library like FastUtil or Trove from generic Scala code. I would like to implement something like

```
def openHashMap[@specialized K, @specialized V]: ${K}2${V}OpenHashMap = 
   new ${K}2${V}OpenHashMap()
```

Where the `${X}` is clearly not valid Scala, but just my meta notation for text substitution,
so that `openHashMap[Long, Double]` would return a `Long2DoubleOpenHashMap` the type would be known at compile time. Is this possible with Scala macros. If so, which flavour? I know there are def macros, implicit macros, fundep materialization, macro annotations, type macros (now discontinued) ... and I think these are different in plain Scala-2.10, 2.10 macro paradise and Scala-2.11. Which, if any, of these are appropriate for this?

Or is there something else that can do this like byte code manipulation, language virtualization, ...? However, I do not believe the alternative I just mentioned can.

Comment: This should be fairly simple with plain `def` macros. Unfortunately I don't have time now to elaborate.

Comment: Availability of different macro-related features in 2.10, paradise and 2.11 is outlined in a table at http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/roadmap.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stealing the idea to use quasiquotes [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838533/instantiate-a-class-with-scala-macro-or-reflection#18838797), we first add the macro-paradise plugin:

```
// build.sbt
scalaVersion := "2.10.2"

resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots")

addCompilerPlugin("org.scala-lang.plugins" % "macro-paradise" % "2.0.0-SNAPSHOT" 
  cross CrossVersion.full)
```

Then the macro looks like this:

```
// src/main/scala/Foo.scala
import reflect.macros.Context
import language.experimental.macros

trait Foo[A]
class IntFoo() extends Foo[Int]
class AnyFoo() extends Foo[Any]

object Foo {
  def apply[A]: Foo[A] = macro applyImpl[A]

  def applyImpl[A](c: Context)(t: c.WeakTypeTag[A]): c.Expr[Foo[A]] = {
    import c.universe._
    val aTpe    = t.tpe
    val prefix  = if (aTpe =:= typeOf[Int]) "Int" else "Any"
    val clazz   = newTypeName(s"${prefix}Foo")
    c.Expr(q"new $clazz()")
  }
}
```

And the test case:

```
// src/test/scala/Test.scala
object Test extends App {
  val fooInt = Foo[Int]
  val fooAny = Foo[Any]

  println(fooInt)
  println(fooAny)
}
```

---

Without the macro-paradise-plugin, you would need to construct the tree by hand, like `New(clazz, ???)`, I couldn't get that to work so gave up, but it certainly would be possible, too.

Comment: Note that the type of `fooInt` is still `Foo[Int]` and not `IntFoo`. I believe for a synthetic macro return type you would need type-macros (and they have not been accepted for standard Scala).

Comment: Actually the type of fooInt even in 2.10.x is IntFoo.

Comment: Also usage of macro paradise here is only necessary for quasiquotes. If one replaces quasiquotes with equivalent manual tree construction, everything will work in vanilla 2.10.

Comment: @EugeneBurmako - ah, I'm surprised. So the return type annotation of `apply` is overriden? Yes, read my last paragraph. I was too lazy to figure out how to invoke the constructor by hand.

Comment: In 2.10 macro expansions can refine return types of macro defs that were used to produce them. In 2.11, it will be a bit different though as described in http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/blackbox-whitebox.html.

Comment: Will this work in generic code? I mean if I define `def f[X] =  ... Foo[X] ...` will the macro expansion only happen when `X` is instantiated or will it use just use `X` directly as the value of `A`?

Comment: @DanielMahler in that case you will need to use reflection instead, I guess, because there is no resolved type `X` available at compile time. Luckily, 2.10 reflection and macros share some things (e.g. the type test).